# How to do smooth Alpha chanel keying with Silverlight 3 Pixel Shaders?

Tags: c#, silverlight, filter, transparency, hlsl

How to do smooth Alpha channel keying with Silverlight 3 Pixel Shaders?

I want some HLSL filter (like this [Shazzam](http://shazzam-tool.com/) HLSL example)

```
             sampler2D  implicitInputSampler : register(S0);


             float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR
             {
               float4 color = tex2D( implicitInputSampler, uv );

             if( color.r + color.g + color.b < 1.9 ) {
             color.rgba = 0;
                 }

             return color;
             }
```

to key not just the color I’m trying to key but for example if dark red consists of red and blue and I’m keying all blue i want to get transparent red.
(Probably this picture can explain what do I want) 
[image: From to Image]
<sub>(source: [narod.ru](http://superior0.narod.ru/CO/R/C/CA.png))</sub>

Comment: For now it sounds like you want to map one of color channels to the alpha channel. How about just doing `color.a = color.b` or `color.a = 1 - color.b` ? If you want to discard blue component you must be able to set it to 0 then explicitly `color.b = 0` .  I guess it should help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just want to subtract a color rather then key it.

```
float4 subtract = ... ; // color you want to remove
float4 color = ... ;

color.r -= subtract.r;
... // for b and g

if ( color.r < 0 )
    color.r = 0;
... // for b and g
```

After this, you can then use a color chooser to pick which color "subtract" would be and remove it. Hope thats what your trying to do.